# How to remove Internet Explorer permanently from Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I tried to remove it from the add/remove program feature, and its been removed. But when I try to search IE. I found it again, and still could run on my computer. What do I do?

Comment: Smartass answer: You don't.

Comment: Fair answer: yes you do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove it through a lot of registry modification, but you shouldn't. It is used to render HTML for almost all apps - Outlook, Word, etc. Uninstalling it from Add/Remove just removes the icons.

Unless you want to manually edit the registry to associate each individual application that renders HTML with a different application, you should leave it as is.

Comment: It's baked into Windows.

Comment: The issue has it's own Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removal_of_Internet_Explorer

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to remove internet explorer completely from XP is doing it prior to the installation. you can manually edit the setup script or use **[nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)** to prevent IE6 from being installed.

However, there are implications regarding the functionality of other windows components and programs, so you should keep at least the core.

It is also possible to [remove IE after the installation](http://www.ntcompatible.com/How_to_completely_remove_Internet_Explorer_6_from_XP_system_t23510.html) but i would not recommend to go down this lane.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open the Start menu and select "Run"
- Type `gpedit.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Go to User Configuration → Administrative Templates → Windows Components → Internet Explorer → InPrivate
- Turn off InPrivate Browsing